# the most devastating argument against user-level thread

Tags: linux, multithreading, operating-system

I am reading sections about user space thread from the book "Modern Operating System". It states that:

> Another, and probably the most devastating argument against user-level threads, is that programmers generally want threads precisely in applications where the threads block often, as, for example, in a multithreaded Web server. These threads are constantly making system calls. Once a trap has occurred to the kernel to carry out the system call, **it is hardly any more work for the kernel to switch threads if the old one has blocked, and having the kernel do this eliminates the need for constantly making select system calls that check to see if read system calls are safe.** For applications that are essentially entirely CPU bound and rarely block, what is the point of having threads at all? No one would seriously propose computing the first n prime numbers or playing chess using threads because there is nothing to be gained by doing it that way.

I am particularly confused about the bold text.
1.Since these are user space threads, how can the kernel do a "switch threads"?
2. "having the kernel do this" , what does "this" here mean?

I thought behaviors are like:
1. "select" call is made, and find following system call is a blocking one.
2. Then the user space thread scheduler makes a thread switching and execute anohter thread.

Comment: Which parts of this post are quoted from the book you're reading, and how old is this book? It seems outdated.

Comment: The last paragraph of Section 2.2.4, Chapter 2. I am using the third edition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, colleges insist on using operating systems textbooks that are confusing and at times nonsensical.

First, what is being described here is ENTIRELY system specific. On SOME operating systems, a synchronous system call will block all threads. This is not true in ALL operating systems.

Second, user threads are the poor man's way of doing them. In ye olde days user threads came into being because there were no operating system support. There are some that promote user threads as being more "efficient" than kernel threads (in theory a library can switch threads faster than the kernel) but this is total BS in practice. User threads are completely obsolete and systems that force developers to use them for threading are OBSOLETE. Even systems older systems like VMS have kernel threads.

In a modern OS course, "user threads" should be a sidebar or historical footnote.

In essence, your book is trying to make a debate where none exists. It's like post WWII U.S. Army assessments comparing the Sherman Tank to the Panther. They talk about things like the Sherman having move comfortable seats to try to make the two sound comparable when, in reality, the Sherman was obsolete and not even in the same class at the Panther.

> 1.Since these are user space threads, how can the kernel do a "switch threads"? 2. "having the kernel do this" , what does "this" here mean?

What they appear to be suggesting is that the thread will block the process when it makes a system call. When the occurs, the operating system will make a context switch. In this case the operating system is making a "thread switch" to another process anyway. The [correct] conclusion they are trying to lead you to then is that this switch take away the user threads have in alleged reduced overhead.

> I thought behaviors are like: 1. "select" call is made, and find following system call is a blocking one. 2. Then the user space thread scheduler makes a thread switching and execute anohter thread.

Let me take the case of a user thread implementation that is not totally blocked by blocking system calls.

1. The library sets a timer for thread switching.
2. The thread start or resumes executing.
3. The thread makes a blocking system service (e.g, select).
4. The operating system switches the process out as part of the system service processing.
5. The timer goes off.
6. The process becomes current again and the OS invokes the timer handler in the library.
7. The library schedules another thread to execute.

The problem you face is that a blocking system service is usually going to have as part of its processing code to trigger a context switch. Because the system does know no about threads (otherwise it would be using kernel threads), a thread calling such a blocking service is going to pass through the code.

Even though the process may have threads that are executable, the operating system has no way to cause them to be executed because it has know knowledge of them because they are managed by a library in the process.